# Sharepoint: List Permission custom message

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to create a custom HTML message when a user does not have access to a specific List instead of showing the user that there are no records?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean. If the user doesn't have access to a list, they won't be able to see the list at all.

On the other hand, if you mean that the user DOES have access to the list but items in the list have unique permissions and he does not have rights to any of those items, then the answer is "no." He will see an empty list and there is no easy way to tell him that the list isn't really empty.